# Unable to uninstall AWS CLI : Cannot uninstall requirement awscli, not installed

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-cli

I was trying to install [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html) on mac but was facing some challenges as aws command was unable to parse the credential file. So I decided to re-install the whole stuff but facing some issues here again.

I am trying `pip uninstall awscli` which says

```
Cannot uninstall requirement awscli, not installed
```

So, i try `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user` which gives me this:

```
    You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: awscli in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: docutils>=0.10 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: PyYAML<=3.12,>=3.10 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: colorama<=0.3.7,>=0.2.5 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: botocore==1.8.29 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.12 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2->awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from botocore==1.8.29->awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from botocore==1.8.29->awscli)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in ./Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore==1.8.29->awscli)
```

Not sure what to do.

Comment: I found this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49606610/7127519

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You run **pip3** `install awscli` but **pip** `uninstall awscli`. Shouldn't it be **pip3** `uninstall awscli`?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.

And I used the following command to fix it.

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir awscli==1.14.39
```