# How to uninstall aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to set up an "Amazon Elastic Container Registry" but I get the following error when using this command: `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2`:

`Unknown options: --no-include-email`

The manual redirects me when this occurs to go to the following page, in order to update my aws cli. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

Which in short means, call `pip install awscli --upgrade --user`. While that works, my cli is not updated. So I removed it at all `pip uninstall awscli`. But I still had the `aws` command available, also when I opened a new session in the terminal...

So I assume I haven't installed my aws cli via pip, but I can not figure out how it does is installed. Can anyone help me out and give me some directions to resolve this issue. So I can remove the current awscli, and install a new version via `pip install awscli --upgrade --user`

Comment: I am on OSX btw, in case that might change the answer

Comment: Did you install using brew?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969391/how-to-upgrade-aws-cli-to-the-latest-version? [Restart may be the answer too...]

Comment: Installation was done by brew indeed, so uninstalling via brew resolved the issue. So not a duplicate since restarting didn't resolved the issue. The question is similair though, how can I find how AWS-CLI is installed

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Answering in case someone else does too. I think I had originally installed it without pip like this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html.
So you just need to uninstall it like this (as instructed in above link):

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/aws
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Then you can re-install it with pip3:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html

Basically:

```
pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
```

Then add it to your path

```
export PATH=/Users/yourname/Library/Python/3.6/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: After deleting the python2 version and installing the python3 version, where does the binary go? After installing awscli and then doing a which aws, it's not found.

Comment: Suggest you to modify the file **~/.bash_profile** adding the export command mentioned by Morgan and restart your terminal and then try **aws --version**. It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 39):

**On ubuntu :**

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove awscli

ln -s /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws /usr/bin/aws
```

Answer (score 17):

Uninstall awscli.

```
pip uninstall awscli -y
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, but unlike Morgan, I prefer to use Homebrew to maintain all my dependencies in a single place.

So what I did was:

1 - uninstall awscli (was installed with pip - python2)

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/aws
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/aws
```

2 - Install awscli using **homebrew**

```
$ brew install awscli
```

Homebrew will install awscli inside Cellar folder: /usr/local/Cellar/awscli

**Note:** I also have python3 installed through Hombrew.

**Links:**

- Amazon-awscli: [Amazon Install awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path)
- Homebrew-awscli: [Homebrew Install awscli](https://www.code2bits.com/how-to-install-awscli-on-macos-using-homebrew/)
- Homebrew-python3: [Homebrew Install python3](https://wsvincent.com/install-python3-mac/)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using mac and used brew to install aws cli. Use `brew uninstall awscli` and try `brew install awscli`

Answer (score 6):

First try to get the path of the installation by using this command in Linux or mac

```
which aws-cli
```

After you get the installation location try removing the directory by using

```
sudo rm -rf "/path resultant from previous command"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone has installed aws-cli using Snap,then following method might be helpful :

First, open the Linux terminal and run the following command in it:

> sudo snap remove aws-cli

The basic command line to remove a snap package is

> sudo snap remove < package >

You have to put the name of a specific application instead of < package >
Once you execute the command successfully, the terminal will ask you to enter the [sudo] password you put for the installation, but if you don’t have any password, press Enter to process it.

After completion of this procedure, you will see that aws-cli gets uninstalled from the system. However, the folder of aws is still present in the snap folder, so execute the following command to remove it:

> sudo snap rm -r aws-cli

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove respective bin & config files:

- rm -rf /usr/local/bin/saml2aws
- rm -rf ~/.aws/config
- rm -rf ~/.aws/credentials

2. Reinstall using the 'install.sh' script

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on linux and it seemed to work
`sudo yum erase awscli`

and get me to a place where when I run:

```
aws --version
zsh: command not found: aws
```